# MySQL unique id across multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables with the following structure:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `car` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `name_UNIQUE` (`name` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `book` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `name_UNIQUE` (`name` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I generating the name column from the title for example: if title: Foo Bar -> name: foo-bar. I'm using this value in the URL. Eariler i had URLs like this /car/foo-bar or /book/foo-bar having same name value in both table wasnt a problem. But i want shorter URLs now: /foo-bar or /foo-bar-2.

How can I make the name value unique across multiple tables?

Answer (score 1):

If you're building an OO application, you would put the name in a separate table and add foreign keys from books and cars to "names"... or whatever that table means in your application, for example *product*.

Otherwise you can enforce it with triggers, but I don't know how triggers work in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force it to be unique, then you could create a third table called `name_reference` for example with a prinary key of the combination of the fields `name` and a field called `type`.  Then you could have book and car have foreign keys to the `name_reference`.